# Can I do this calculation in a merge statement?

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to do a calculation during a merge and it is not working. Is it even possible to this during a merge update? Or am I just missing something

I am using SQL Server for Azure 2018. I can verify that non calculations are being updated into table during merge. I have no issues with the insert

```
MERGE table1 AS s
USING (
SELECT @OId AS oID, @Partno AS partno, @PreviousTotal AS PreviousTotal, 
@YearTotal AS YearTotal) AS source
ON s.oId = source.oId AND s.partno = source.partno
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET  
        UpdatedTotal = (@YearTotal + s.YearTotal) - @PreviousTotal,
        PreviousTotal = source.PreviousTotal,
        ReportDate = GetDate()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (...)
VALUES (...)
```

I just need to do the calculation before I update the record

Comment: If this is in a proc you could just update the new table after the merge. It may be faster as well. That is what I would do.

Comment: Thx @briskovich This is not in a stored procedure - I actually ended up doing the calculation in .net unfortunately. I will keep this in mind in the future though